# how to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR function to extract a substring from a string?

Tags: sql, regex, teradata

I need to extract the word and the sequence of words from the error log.

below log examples:

```
2019.06.08 14:32:36 ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50.
2019.06.08 14:32:36 ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50. (ef)
2019.06.08 14:32:36 ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in dload50.
2019.06.08 14:32:36 ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in dload50. (ef)
message=[NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50. (ef)
message=[NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in dload50. (ef)
message=[NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50. (ee)
message=[NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in dload50. (ee)
```

I need to extract substring:

error_log:

> [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50.

without (eg)

and username:
for example:

> aload50

username can be:

aload01 to aload999

and

dload01 to dload999

```
select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR('2019.06.08 14:32:36  ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] error_message[Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50.',' regexp_for_error_log') AS error_log,
REGEXP_SUBSTR('2019.06.08 14:32:36  ERR 10298587    2019-06-07  PROJECT_NAME    script.sql  4483    2646 HY000 [NCR] [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50.',' regexp_for_user_name') AS user_name,
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ output you are expecting here?

Comment: @jarlh database oracle

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 
error_log: [Teradata DBMS] : No more spool space in aload50 

user_name: aload50

Comment: @dnoeth I use. Logs with errors of ETL processing on Teradata I have on Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `REGEXP_REPLACE` here with a capture group:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(log, '.*(\[Teradata DBMS\] : .* [^.]+)\..*', '\1') AS error_log,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(log, '.*\[Teradata DBMS\] : .* ([^.]+)\..*', '\1') AS user_name
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: You are right.
I did something wrong.
Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @MartinusP No, I did something wrong, I didn't test the code at first.  Glad to help you :-)

Comment: hi @Tim Biegeleisen 
do you know how from the string: "[Teradata DBMS]: No more spool space in aload50." get username aload50 ? by modification `REGEXP_REPLACE(log, '.*\[Teradata DBMS\] : .* ([^.]+)\..*', '\1') AS user_name` `

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of the regex, or something else?

Comment: I would need a solution where the source for user_name is the error_log column from the previous solution
`REGEXP_REPLACE(error_log, '.*(\[Teradata DBMS\] : .* [^.]+)\..*', '\1') as user_name`
i.e. with string [Teradata DBMS]: No more spool space in aload50. cut username: aload50

Comment: probably it will be a minimal modification of the previous solution to extract the last word from the string?